# Is possible for Firebase to merge email auth and phone auth without password for getCredential

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
```

is possible for get credential without the password of above line of code.

Comment: please write your question in detail so that others can understand first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. But using a different Authentication System. 
EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD would be your solution.

```
getCredentialWithLink(String email, String emailLink)
```

In this case, you don't need a password.
Further reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/EmailAuthProvider#public-static-authcredential-getcredentialwithlink-string-email,-string-emaillink